# Basic Cell Fracture not appearing to work

Tags: add-on

I'm new to Blender, and am using Blender 2.78b, and I thought I would try cell fracturing a cube. I turned on the Cell Fracture add-on in User Preferences and subdivided the cube a  couple of times. I tried to use the Cell Fracture add-on, and it seemed to be working like it did in the tutorial I was watching, but when it was done the cube returned to its original state. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Works fine and dandy (even without subdiv). Check *Layer 2*.

Answer (score 1):

I am noticing on 2.77 that Cell Fracture will add the fracture cells to the outline, but they are not visible.  If I save the blend, restart Blender and load the blend, then the cells will show up.  I don't know why this behaves this way and would love to know if there is a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's because the Fractured Cube was moved to the second layer (if you were in the first one). The Cell Fracture Addon with the default settings move the fractured object to the next layer. Anyway, I don't think using Cell Fracture Addon to Fracture Things in Blender is a good idea. It's slow and it doesn't work sometimes. Use this custom Build:
http://graphicall.org/1148

It's way Faster due to the fact that's developed in C, and you can use different tools to fracture your object instead of the Boolean one. This means less artifacts in the fractured mesh and way faster fracturing.

Answer (score 1):

[Switch to the next layer or re-do cell fracture after unchecking "Next Layer" option.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odzW2pU3OX4) (video link)

The fractures are most likely on a new layer, because you possibly forgot to uncheck "Next Layer"

[image: Cell Fracture UI]

You can switch to layer 1 or undo and repeat with "Next Layer" unchecked.